# How can I use docker for drupal?

Tags: docker, drupal

I had read about docker. Can anyone give ideas on what exactly docker does and whether it can be implemented for developing drupal based applications?

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. Please got through the link on how to ask effective questions. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker is a container application that makes it simple and easy to run application processes in a container, which are like VMs(Virtual Machines). Docker containers are more resource friendly, more portable and light weighted applications.

For more information read URL: https://www.kelltontech.com/kellton-tech-blog/docker-installation-centos-7

and for making drupal work with docker read URL: https://blog.wodby.com/continuous-integration-and-delivery-drupal-docker-circleci-192c6ac97087

Answer (score 0):

with docker you can create containers, where all your parts of the applications run. in docker, there is golden rule where you have to create for each component a docker-container. for example, OS with php runs in one container, sql runs in one container.

Docker is good for drupal (i use it myself most of the time) because you can setup a new Drupal project in very short time.

you need Dockerfiles where you define what programms runs inside of the container. You can find finished containers on the Docker webside. https://docs.docker.com/

because you need more than one container, i would suggest to use docker-compose. with docker-compose you can configure and setup an environment of multiple docker-container. https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/